# Training Loss Isnt Decreasing Across Epochs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, training-data

I am trying to construct a siamese neural network to take in two facial expressions and output the probability that the two images are similar. I have 5 people, with 10 expressions per person, so 50 total images, but with Siamese, I can generate 2500 pairs (with repetition). I have already run dlib's facial landmark detection on each of the 50 images, so each of the two inputs to the siamese net are two flattened 136,1 element arrays. The siamese structure is below:

```python
input_shape = (136,)
left_input = Input(input_shape, name = 'left')
right_input = Input(input_shape, name = 'right')

convnet = Sequential()
convnet.add(Dense(50,activation="relu"))

encoded_l = convnet(left_input)
encoded_r = convnet(right_input)

L1_layer = Lambda(lambda tensors:K.abs(tensors[0] - tensors[1]))

L1_distance = L1_layer([encoded_l, encoded_r])
prediction = Dense(1,activation='relu')(L1_distance)
siamese_net = Model(inputs=[left_input,right_input],outputs=prediction)

optimizer = Adam()
siamese_net.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",optimizer=optimizer)
```

I have an array called x_train, which is 80% of all possible labels and whose elements are a list of lists. Data is a 5x10x64x2 matrix, where there are 5 ppl, 10 expressions per, 64 facial landmarks, and 2 positons (x,y) per landmark

```python
x_train = [ [ [Person, Expression] , [Person, Expression] ], ...]
data = np.load('data.npy')
```

My train loop goes as follows:

```python
def train(data, labels, network, epochs, batch_size):
    track_loss  = defaultdict(list)

    for i in range(0, epochs):
        iterations = len(labels)//batch_size
        remain = len(labels)%batch_size
        shuffle(labels)
        print('Epoch%s-----' %(i + 1))
        for j in range(0, iterations):
            batch = [j*batch_size, j*batch_size + batch_size]
            if(j == iterations - 1):
                batch[1] += remain
            mini_batch = np.zeros(shape = (batch[1] - batch[0], 2, 136))
            for k in range(batch[0], batch[1]):
                prepx = data[labels[k][0][0],labels[k][0][1],:,:]
                prepy = data[labels[k][1][0],labels[k][1][1],:,:]
                mini_batch[k - batch[0]][0] = prepx.flatten()
                mini_batch[k - batch[0]][1] = prepy.flatten()
            targets = np.array([1 if(labels[i][0][1] == labels[i][1][1]) else 0 for i in range(batch[0], batch[1])])
            new_batch = mini_batch.reshape(batch[1] - batch[0], 2, 136, 1)
            new_targets = targets.reshape(batch[1] - batch[0], 1)
            #print(mini_batch.shape, targets.shape)
            loss=siamese_net.train_on_batch(
            {
             'left': mini_batch[:, 0, :],
             'right': mini_batch[:, 1, :]
            },targets)
            track_loss['Epoch%s'%(i)].append(loss)
    return network, track_loss
siamese_net, track_loss = train(data, x_train,siamese_net, 20, 30)
```

The value of each element in the target array is either a 0 or 1, depending on whether the two expressions inputted into the net are different or the same.

Although, I have seen in the omniglot example there were far more images and test images, my neural net doesn't have any decrease in loss.

EDIT:

Here is the new loss with the fixed target tensor:

```python
Epoch1-----Loss: 1.979214
Epoch2-----Loss: 1.631347
Epoch3-----Loss: 1.628090
Epoch4-----Loss: 1.634603
Epoch5-----Loss: 1.621578
Epoch6-----Loss: 1.631347
Epoch7-----Loss: 1.631347
Epoch8-----Loss: 1.631347
Epoch9-----Loss: 1.621578
Epoch10-----Loss: 1.634603
Epoch11-----Loss: 1.634603
Epoch12-----Loss: 1.621578
Epoch13-----Loss: 1.628090
Epoch14-----Loss: 1.624834
Epoch15-----Loss: 1.631347
Epoch16-----Loss: 1.634603
Epoch17-----Loss: 1.628090
Epoch18-----Loss: 1.631347
Epoch19-----Loss: 1.624834
Epoch20-----Loss: 1.624834
```

I want to know how to improve my architecture and training procedure, or even data prep, in order to improve the performance of the neural net. I assumed that using dlib's facial landmark detection would simplify complexity of the neural net, but I am starting to doubt that hypothesis.

Comment: `targets = np.array([1 if(labels[k][0][1] == labels[k][1][1]) else 0 for i in range(batch[0], batch[1])])`.  Is `k` to be `i`?

Comment: wow, that was it.

Comment: however, here is the loss across epochs is barely decreasing. I will edit the question

Comment: `prediction = Dense(1,activation='relu')(L1_distance)`.  Would you want to use "sigmoid" activation since the target variable is binary?

Comment: Also, I would check the accuracy and validation performance.  Then error analysis; Since you only have a few people in the data, it would be interesting to see which pairs the model gets confused.

Comment: actually, i found that the real error comes from the fact that data input is only around 8% similar expression examples while the rest are different expression examples. I made a random batch function which makes sure that 50% of the batch has similar expression data, and this massively improved the error